# Simba BigQuery driver is not using the cache

Tags: database, google-cloud-platform, caching, google-bigquery, odbc

I am using the Simba BigQuery ODBC driver to read data from BigQuery. The SQL statements run fine and I am able to retrieve the results. But if I run the same query (they are just simple select statements) multiple times, they're all being executed every time (and, hence, billed) instead of retrieving it from the cache. My understanding, only the first time should be executed and the later attempts to just hit the cache and give me the results.

I have explicitly set the ODBC setting to use cache (UseQueryCache = 1). I'm not sure why the subsequent queries do not hit the cache.

Is it to do with my ODBC settings or does Simba in general not use cache at all?

Answer (score 1):

There are few factors for a query not being cached:

> - When a destination table is specified in the job configuration, the Google Cloud console, the bq command-line tool, or the API
> - If any of the referenced tables or logical views have changed since the results were previously cached
> - When any of the tables referenced by the query have recently received streaming inserts (table has data in the write-optimized storage) even if no new rows have arrived
> - If the query uses non-deterministic functions; for example, date and time functions such as CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() and CURRENT_DATE, and other functions such as SESSION_USER(), it returns different values depending on when a query is executed
> - If you are querying multiple tables using a wildcard
> - If the cached results have expired; typical cache lifetime is 24 hours, but the cached results are best-effort and may be invalidated sooner
> - If the query runs against an external data source other than Cloud Storage. (GoogleSQL queries on Cloud Storage are supported by cached query results.)
> - If the query runs against a table protected by column-level security, results may not be cached.
> - If the query runs against a table protected by row-level security, then the results are not cached.

As long as cached query is stored in a temporary table, you will not be billed for these temporary tables.

In BQ console we can verify this with checking the job information tab after running a query (Results cached):

[image]

You can visit the [link here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cached-results) for its documentation.